# Ionic 2: why change event is not working on ion-select?

Tags: angular, ionic2

Why change event is not working on ion-select?

I tried with following statement:

```
<ion-select formControlName="shippingMethod (change)="shippingMethodChange($event)">
```

I also tried with ionChange by using following and This is working:

```
<ion-select formControlName="shippingMethod (ionChange)="shippingMethodChange($event)">
```

It is being said "We can use Angular event bindings to respond to any DOM event" and here is the doc for the change event

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/change

Comment: hope this will help for you

  <ion-select [(ngModel)]="gender" (ionChange)="onSelectChange($event)">
    <ion-option value="f">Female</ion-option>
    <ion-option value="m">Male</ion-option>
  </ion-select>
then in your page:

  onSelectChange(selectedValue: any) {
    console.log('Selected', selectedValue);
  }

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`ion-select` is a custom component by Ionic 2 . Check [api here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/select/Select/).
It is built by ionic leveraging an `alertController/actionsheetcontroller` based on developer requirement.

It does not use change event like an HTML select and the correct event emitted is `ionChange`.

**Edit**
And the Event emitted for clicking on `ion-option` is `ionSelect`.

Check this [github issue](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/7807).

Component docs [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/components/#select)

Hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 14):

You can use it the following way:

```
  <ion-select [(ngModel)]="gender" (ionChange)="onSelectChange($event)">
    <ion-option value="G">Colombo</ion-option>
    <ion-option value="M">Galle</ion-option>
  </ion-select>
```

then in your .ts file:

```
  onSelectChange(selectedValue: any) {
    console.log('Selected', selectedValue);
  }
```

Comment: Dunno why this was downvoted, ionChange worked for me instead of ionSelect. Thanks @CodeMind

Comment: Since 2 days, I am trying to find answer and here it is. Thanks Bro...

Comment: Worked for ionic 3 :)

Comment: Mind the code: I thought (change) was the syntax :-)

Answer (score 1):

The question keeps popping up every now and then. According to the [documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/option/Option/) ionSelect is an output event on option (ion-option)

Here is an example usage

```
<ion-select>
  <ion-option *ngFor="let opt of options" [value] = "opt" (ionSelect)="triggerMe(opt)">{{opt}}</ion-option>
</ion-select>
```

And then

```
triggerMe(value: string): void {
  console.log("selected value", value);
}
```